# How to connect to SQL Server Developer (windows edition) in a container on Win10 from outside the container

Tags: sql-server, windows, docker

I got the docker image for SQL Server Developer edition and started it up:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker ps -aa
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                    NAMES
81347866fc2b        microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer   "powershell -Command…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour (healthy)   0.0.0.0:1433->3341/tcp   trusting_mccarthy
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

It's listening on port 3341 as you can see.  the IP is:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}'  8
172.17.234.173
```

HOwever I cannot connect to it from the host:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> sqlcmd -S 172.17.234.173,3341
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

Must be doing something wrong.  any hints?

PS: I can't connect to 1433 either:

```
PS P:\> sqlcmd -S 172.17.234.173,1433
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
PS P:\>
```

Docker Run command used:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>" `
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 `
   -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-server-windows-developer
```

*note* I've started with 1433:3341 as well.  No joy either way

Comment: Provided the port information are correct, you look like you switched port between docker side and host side. Ie : your should do sqlcmd -S 172.17.234.173,1433 (this is "published port -> container exposed port")

Comment: I thought so to, but that also fails (posted an update)

Comment: And are you sure the sqlserver is 3441? The documentation (https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer/) says it's 1433... thus you would publish 1433:1433 when running your image. Did you change something inside the conf?

Comment: I changed it (see above) to align with our normal practices.  however using the default port 1433 gives me the same problem.

Comment: Can you add your "docker run " command (or whatever command) you use?